# Google Sheets, Reorder filter views list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

Ive got a google drive spreadsheet with lots of filter views.

Ive been adding them on an adhoc basis, and the list is growing a bit long 
making it hard to find the filters when i need them.

Is it possible to reorder the list of the filter views, either alphabetically or by a custom order ?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Sheets UI, the Google Apps Script service and the Google Sheets API do not include a way to sort the list of filter views on the Google Sheets UI, but the filter views are editable so you could each item in the filter view to make have the settings that you want.

NOTE: Google Apps Script doesn't support filter views directly but you could use the Google Sheets Advance Service

Related

- [Mass Delete Filter Views in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54632698/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to delve into the [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) or [Filter View](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#filterview), a "quick and dirty" workaround would be to rename your filters giving them a serial number: `01-myfilter`, `02-yourfilter`, `03-onemore`.

Rather a practical solution of re-naming than a "Google developer solution".